# Which model of xbox 360 kinect camera should I buy?

Tags: navigation, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-trusty, gazebo-ros-openni-kinect

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I need the xbox kinect camera to do mapping on my AGV project , but I don't know which model should I buy.
I'm using kinetic on ubuntu 16.04. Also does I need a different model of the kinect camera if I'll use it on indigo (ubuntu14.04)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280949/which-model-of-xbox-360-kinect-camera-should-i-buy-?/) by [Mahmoud Omar](https://answers.ros.org/users/33436/mahmoud-omar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [kinect](http://ksassets.timeincuk.net/wp/uploads/sites/54/2010/11/14355-kinectsensor-1.jpg) is supported by kinetic and indigo [the package](http://wiki.ros.org/libfreenect). About the xbox one kinect, i found [this](https://github.com/ethz-asl/kinect2-ros) repo but i never used

---

Originally posted by [rdelgadov](https://answers.ros.org/users/33433/rdelgadov/) with karma: 51 on 2018-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0